# How to set equivalent of web.xml JNDI <env-entry> in a Spring Boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, jndi

Referring to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28277433/1013394), I'd like to setup the equivalent of this `web.xml` configuration in a JSF / JoinFaces / SpringBoot application (that doesn't have `web.xml`).

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>jsf/ClientSideSecretKey</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>[AES key in Base64 format]</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Essentially `<env-entry>` declares a web application context attribute.

You can [initialize your servlet context](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-context-initializer) and provide the equivalent servlet context attributes in your Spring Boot application.

For that purpose, you can register a bean that implements the [ServletContextInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletContextInitializer.html) interface (or [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) if your app has to be deployed in a traditional servlet container). For example:

```java
public class JsfServletContextInitializer implements ServletContextInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.setAttribute("jsf/ClientSideSecretKey", "[AES key in Base64 format]");
  }

}
```

Do not forget to register it as a bean in your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring boot and embedded tomcat server, you can add `<env-entry>` programmatically with the following configuration.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    
    
    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat tomcat) {
                tomcat.enableNaming(); 
                return super.getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
            }

            @Override 
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {

                // adding <resource-ref>
                ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
                resource.setName("jdbc/myJndiResource");
                resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
                resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "org.postgresql.Driver");

                resource.setProperty("url", "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:port/dbname");
                resource.setProperty("username", "username");
                resource.setProperty("password", "password");
                context.getNamingResources()
                       .addResource(resource); 
                
                // adding <env-entry>
                ContextEnvironment ce = new ContextEnvironment();
                ce.setName("jsf/ClientSideSecretKey");
                ce.setType(String.class.getName());
                ce.setValue("[AES key in Base64 format]");
                context.getNamingResources().addEnvironment(ce); 
                
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Once defined the jndi naming resources they can be accessed in your application using `JndiTemplate` of `InitialContext`.

```
JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
String str = (String) jndiTemplate.lookup("java:comp/env/jsf/ClientSideSecretKey");
```

Hope this helps you in resolving your problem.